# how to align anchor in div without using margin

Tags: html, alignment, anchor, center, newsletter

I am working on Newsletter HTML and I can't give margin to center align the divs. How can I align the button into the center of the div. Here is the simple code

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600">  
<tr>
<td>  

<div style="text-align:center;">
<a href="#" style="display:block; width:150px; text-decoration:none; font-weight:bold; color:#fff; background:#c72622; font-size:20px; border-radius:7px; -webkit-border-radius:7px; padding-top:10px; padding-bottom:10px;">
Buy Now
</a>
</div>

</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: is some one there to help me out :S ??? Its been 2 hours there is no response yet :(

Answer (score 0):

Add `align="center"` to your containing table cell. This is the best way to center align in HTML email.

Answer (score 0):

steer clear of all padding and margin, they are poorly / wrongly supported in a lot of clients. use lots of nested tables and `<tr>` `<td height="1234" align="center/left/right">` instead. Avoid the `<table align="center/left/right">` attribute wherever you can because outlook will generate extra whitespace. I use `<table align="center">` for my wrapper tables.

For vertical alignment, use the `valign` attribute of your `<td>`s and `<tr>`s. Works best if another `td` in the row has an image with the height you'd like to vertical align to.

Comment: You should use the `align="center"` on your wrapper table `<td>` instead. You never need align on the table tag itself. It also doesn't create extra space when used on `<td>`.